# How to prevent ssh user to login if same user is still logged in?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login

For security reasons, I want to restrict users to have more than one ssh connection.
In terminal, if I check $ last user , I'll find the user is still logged in.
Is any solution to check if user is still logged in don't allow to login again?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/number-of-ssh-connections-on-a-single-linux-machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sftp concurrent connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/392749/sftp-concurrent-connection)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, IMHO the fist is better match :)

Comment: IMO as well, but we can't close as a duplicate on a different site. The second answers it as well and it's not necessary to replicate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly limit the `ssh` connections. But you can limit the logins of this user. Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add line:

```
specificuser  hard    maxlogins   1
```

This will limit the logins to 1 for `specificuser` (independently if we talk about `ssh`, `telnet` or console logins)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the option "MaxStartups " in the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config file":

```
MaxStartups 1
```

Then restart the ssh service.
This setting allows a maximum of one connection for each user

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same user for all users on your company (aka `root`), you can add the next code on the begging of the `/etc/profile` file to filter one user by IP address:

```
# Limit logins to one user by IP
NEW_LOGIN=$(last -n 1 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
CURRENT_LOGINS=$(w -hs | awk '{print $3}' | grep "$NEW_LOGIN" | wc -l)
if [ "$CURRENT_LOGINS" -ge "2" ]; then
  echo "Only one login per user/IP is allowed, closing this connection to $NEW_LOGIN"
  exit 1
fi
```